# How to well support misspell words on Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I have a question on how to make Azure Cognitive Search support misspell cases. For example: if I make search "arohi communications inc", I hope that "aarohi communications inc" is able to show on the result. However, it doesn't. I have try the fuzzy search such as: (arohi communications inc)~ etc. But no luck. Azure Cognitive Search claims that it should support this case, but it doesn't. And if I process fuzzy search, there are a lot nothing related results shown, which doesn't make sense. Does anyone provide suggestions or advices? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation about [Fuzzy Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-query-fuzzy#what-is-fuzzy-search), you need to add the tilde after each word in the sentence. In the documentation, there is the sample for "University of Washington" with Fuzzy Search:

"For example, if your query includes three terms "university of washington", a graph is created for every term in the query search=university~ of~ washington~ (there's no stop-word removal in fuzzy search, so "of" gets a graph).
The graph consists of up to 50 expansions, or permutations, of each term, capturing both correct and incorrect variants in the process. The engine then returns the topmost relevant matches in the response.
For a term like "university", the graph might have "unversty, universty, university, universe, inverse"."

So, in your case, you would have to look for search=aarohi~ communitations~ inc~

Below is the image of the response.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I have tried to search "arohi~ communitations~ inc~", there is no "Aarohi communitations  inc" shown. And I search "arohi~", there is no "Aarohi" related results, either.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a different analyzer than Standard or have something different than what's expected for Fuzzy. Please raise a support ticket here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request since this will need you to provide your index JSON configuration and the documents where the data is found. Since this data is not to be shared publicly, in this case the support team would be able to point at your specific configuration issue that is not letting you find the results.